# Driver Problem in Sybase

Tags: .net, odbc, sap-ase

I am working on XP m\c and right now I don't have sybase install.

But My server has the sybase 12.5 (that much I only know). I am using web service to talk to that server. How can I call the data from that server,

For this I am using a webservice which has some web methods that are using specific connection string. Right now I am using ODBC connection string for that.

I want to know do I need to install SYbase clinet at my m/c to call server data. OR else How shouls I proceed,

Thaks

Answer (score 0):

Either you need to install a Sybase client, or you could use a "direct" ODBC driver (aka. ["Type B"](http://uda.openlinksw.com/odbc-sybase-st/)?), which will speaks [TDS](http://www.faqs.org/faqs/databases/sybase-faq/part15/) directly to the server without needing the Sybase client libraries.

Answer (score 0):

You will want to install the Sybase SDK on your webserver which includes Open Client and support for ADO .Net if you don't want to continue using ODBC.  I think you need to contact sales in order to get a copy though.  See [this page](http://www.sybase.com/products/allproductsa-z/softwaredeveloperkit).